# Connect and run PowerShell command from Web API

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, runspace

I am trying to run a PowerShell command from a Web Api. All I ever get is this error
The term 'Get-MailUser' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
I can run the same code from a PowerShell 7 command and it works fine. I am using the Microsoft PowerShell SDK in the project which is showing at level 7.1.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the code I am using.

```
          if (powershell == null)
            {
                using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
                {
                    runspace.Open();
                    powershell = PowerShell.Create();
                    powershell.Runspace = runspace;

                    PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
                    command.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddArgument("RemoteSigned");
                    command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
                    command.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddParameter("Name", "PowerShellGet");
                    command.AddCommand("Install-Module").AddParameter("Name", "ExchangeOnlineManagement").AddParameter("Force");
                    command.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddParameter("Name", "ExchangeOnlineManagement");
                    command.AddCommand("Connect-ExchangeOnline").AddParameter("CertificateThumbPrint", "mythumbprint")
                                                                   .AddParameter("AppId", "my app id")
                                                                   .AddParameter("Organization", "mycompany.onmicrosoft.com");
                    command.AddCommand("Get-MailUser").AddParameter("Identity", "myemailaddress");

                    powershell.Commands = command;
                    // Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
                    var t1 = powershell.Invoke<PSSession>();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Get-MailUser` is part of the [ExchangePowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/?view=exchange-ps) module. You are installing the `ExchangeOnlineManagement` module which has a `Get-EXOMailbox` cmdlet.

Comment: You'll want to call `AddStatement()` in between the different commands

Comment: @Theo ahhhh...yep. That works but with that module I can't add/update mailboxes or contacts, only get them. That's with the Powershell SDK nuget. Using desktop version I can add/update all day long. Back to the drawing board :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make successive calls to `AddCommand`, you're effectively composing a *pipeline* - so the equivalent to your code in PowerShell would be:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned |New-PSSession |Import-Module -Name PowerShellGet |Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -Force |Import-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement |Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateThumbPrint mythumbprint -AppId "my app id" -Organization mycompany.onmicrosoft.com |Get-MailUser -Identity myemailaddress
```

... which is probably *not* what you intended.

Remember to call `AddStatement()` in between commands instead:

```
command.AddCommand("Install-Module").AddParameter("Name", "ExchangeOnlineManagement").AddParameter("Force");
command.AddStatement();
command.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddParameter("Name", "ExchangeOnlineManagement");
command.AddStatement();
// ... and so forth
```

Comment: that gets rid of the cmdlet not found problem. I tried both Get-MailUser and Get-EXOMailbox, both return with no results. If I run this script from my computer it runs fine. 
Maybe my commands are incorrect?

inline `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned 
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -Force
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Import-Module -Name PowerShellGet
Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateThumbPrint "mythimb" -AppID "my app id" -Organization "my company.onmicrosoft.com"
Get-EXOMailbox`